# Redirect URLs from another server

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I recently took over a website. The Old developer is not contactable. The old site URL is still up but doesn't load. I don't have any access to the old hosting account.

I've tried using a 301 Redirect but it doesn't work. Can I accomplish this without having access to the old URL's host?

Thank You

Comment: If you have access to the DNS server just rewrite the DNS entry for that URL.

Comment: You're going to need access to the registrar that host the domain name. If you don't know who the registrar is you could do a find out - https://whois.icann.org/en - and then contact the registrar and dispute ownership.